# I have background color in button.How can I set selector for button also?

Tags: android-layout

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/info_button"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:textColor="@color/white"
 android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
 android:onClick="getInformation"
 android:text="@string/information"
 android:layout_height="48dp" />
```

I  have selector below  I  want   to  use  in  button and  use  background  color  also.Is  there  any  way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/btn_preess" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/btn_preess1" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/btn_preess1"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: This is your *selector* file so use it with *Button* using `android:background="@drawable/selectorname"`.

Comment: Ok  nice  answer  jay  but  I  have done with  state pressed and state focussed  as  color  primary